# the div tag is not showing when i call its content in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html

the html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>Select Payment Option</span>
 <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1" 
 onchange="fun_showtextbox()">
 <option value="x">Cash</option>
  <option value="y">Cheque</option>
  <option value="z">Mobile Money</option>

 </select>
  </div>
  <div class ="row" style="display:none;" id="mobileno_textbox">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty is-focused">
    <label class ="control-label">Cash</label>
  <input type="text" name="select" "id="select"class="form- 
  control"placeholder="number">
 </div>
 </div>                                                                   
 </div>
 <div class ="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty is-focused">
  <label class ="control-label">Amount: </label>
   <input type="text" name="select" "id="select"class="form-control" 
  placeholder="amount">
   </div>
   </div>                                                                     
 </div>
```

the div content in number does not show after calling the function.
jquery code:

```
function fun_showtextbox()
 {
  var select_status=$('#select1').val();
 /* select  from select box then show my text box */

  if(select_status == "y")
   {
    $('#mobileno_textbox').show();// By using this id you can show your 
  content    
   }
     else
   {
    $('#mobileno_textbox').hide();// otherwise hide   
  }

 }
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong but div content for id="mobileno_textbox" is not showing?

Comment: Does the function trigger whenever you select?. Try to put console log on the If and else statement so that you will know where it goes and debug it.

Comment: nothing happens@Joven28

Comment: if you have the word "content" in the comment after // ... on a next line, like it is in the code that you have supplied, then it breaks your code and it won't work.

Comment: and you also have messy quote marks in: <input type="text" name="select" "id="select"class="form-control" 
  placeholder="amount">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you may have a few typos. especially your Id. you have `"id="select"`

anyway I think I have it working here.

https://jsfiddle.net/qLg1fy9d/

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  fun_showtextbox();
  $('#select1').change(function() {
    fun_showtextbox();
  })
});

function fun_showtextbox() {
  var select_status = $('#select1').val();
  /* select  from select box then show my text box */

  if (select_status == "y") {
    $('#mobileno_textbox').show(); // By using this id you can show your 
    content
  } else {
    $('#mobileno_textbox').hide(); // otherwise hide   
  }

}
```

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <span>Select Payment Option</span>
    <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">
       <option value="x">Cash</option>
      <option value="y">Cheque</option>
      <option value="z">Mobile Money</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="display:none;" id="mobileno_textbox">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty is-focused">
      <label class="control-label">Cash</label>
      <input type="text" name="select" id="select" class="form-control" placeholder="number">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty is-focused">
      <label class="control-label">Amount: </label>
      <input type="text" name="select" id="select" class="form-control" placeholder="amount">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i seem to have trouble showing only two divs assigned to cheque.  how can i hide two divs that will only show once cheque is selected without messing up the logic? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that you have no jquery included in your html file. This is working with plain js code.

```js
function fun_showtextbox()
 {
  var select_status = document.getElementById('select1').value;
 /* select  from select box then show my text box */

  if(select_status == "y")
   {
    document.getElementById('mobileno_textbox').style.display = "block";
   }
     else
   {
    document.getElementById('mobileno_textbox').style.display = "none";   
  }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>Select Payment Option</span>
 <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1" 
 onchange="fun_showtextbox()">
 <option value="x">Cash</option>
  <option value="y">Cheque</option>
  <option value="z">Mobile Money</option>

 </select>
  </div>
  <div class ="row" style="display:none;" id="mobileno_textbox">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty is-focused">
    <label class ="control-label">Cash</label>
  <input type="text" name="select" "id="select"class="form- 
  control"placeholder="number">
 </div>
 </div>                                                                   
 </div>
 <div class ="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty is-focused">
  <label class ="control-label">Amount: </label>
   <input type="text" name="select" "id="select"class="form-control" 
  placeholder="amount">
   </div>
   </div>                                                                     
 </div>



</body>
</html>
```